# Argo Workflow throwing '/bin/sh: arithmetic syntax error'

Tags: argo-workflows

I am new to using Argo Workflows. I have written down a sample workflow for demo purposes. Below is the attached workflow YAML in which I am facing this issue in the last step. The last step **sayHello** is erroring out with exit status 2 and the logs show up the error to be :

> '/bin/sh: arithmetic syntax error'

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: program-1-prints
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: addTwoNos
            template: addTwoNosTemplate
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: a
                  value: '2'
                - name: b
                  value: '4'
        - - name: addTenToResult
            template: addTwoNosTemplate
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: a
                  value: '{{steps.addTwoNos.outputs.result}}'
                - name: b
                  value: '10'
        - - name: sayHello
            template: sayHello
            when: '{{steps.addTenToResult.outputs.result}} > 10'
    - name: addTwoNosTemplate
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: a
          - name: b
      container:
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
          - '-c'
        args:
          - 'echo $(( {{inputs.parameters.a}} + {{inputs.parameters.b}} ))'
    - name: sayHello
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: result
            value: '{{steps.addTenToResult.outputs.result}}'
      container:
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
          - '-c'
        args:
          - 'echo $(( {{inputs.parameters.result}} ))'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` input to the `sayHello` template must be passed explicitly from the third step of the `main` template.

`steps.addTenToResult.outputs.result` has no meaning in the `sayHello` template definition. Variables starting with `steps.` only have meaning in steps templates (i.e. templates with the `steps` field populated, like in `main`).

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: program-1-prints
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: addTwoNos
            template: addTwoNosTemplate
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: a
                  value: '2'
                - name: b
                  value: '4'
        - - name: addTenToResult
            template: addTwoNosTemplate
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: a
                  value: '{{steps.addTwoNos.outputs.result}}'
                - name: b
                  value: '10'
        - - name: sayHello
            template: sayHello
            when: '{{steps.addTenToResult.outputs.result}} > 10'
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: result
                  value: '{{steps.addTenToResult.outputs.result}}'
    - name: addTwoNosTemplate
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: a
          - name: b
      container:
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
          - '-c'
        args:
          - 'echo $(( {{inputs.parameters.a}} + {{inputs.parameters.b}} ))'
    - name: sayHello
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: result
      container:
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
          - '-c'
        args:
          - 'echo $(( {{inputs.parameters.result}} ))'
```